# How to deserialize hidden behind ServiceProvider class object in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, netbeans-platform

We create a program that builds logic circuits and use **Lookup** and **ServiceProvider** mechanisms of NetBeans Platform to get the all available logic elements onto the UI palette.

Model (MVC) have a BasicElement class which is a ServiceProvider of all elements. This class is public, it's package is publicly exported and the View module have a dependency on it. View module knows only about this Model module. When someone adds new module with a pack of elements **annotated** with @ServiceProvider then View loads new found with Lookup elements onto the palette. Then user can d'n'd elements from the palette onto the scene, create some circuits and save (serialise) them.

The problem is when the program tries to open saved file (deserialise elements) exception arises. Because no module knows about (is dependent on) modules with elements (and packages in those modules could be not exported publicly). Elements are only annotated and it's enough for them to get to the user.

Is there a possibility **without** every time **adding dependency** on new modules with elements to **deserialise** those. Or in general is there a way to deserialise class objects that are hidden behind ServiceProvider class.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this exact problem a while ago. After much research, I found out that you can change the class loader used by the ObjectInputStream. Have a look at my blog post on the topic detailing my solution. http://www.pellissier.co.za/hermien/?p=179

Comment: Just FYI, it would be best to move the solution into the answer itself.